# Adicionando uma condicional na TAG do XML

Tags: php, xml, condição

Estou trabalhando num arquivo.xml para ser enviado ao um serviço. Porém a dúvida é como adicionar uma condicional no XML, ou seja, eu tenho N tipos de cobertura que serão preenchidos em um formulário e nem todas as coberturas serão informadas.
Mas os dados serão oriundos do banco de dados.

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<hsCobertura>
  <entry>
  <key>$codigoTipoCobertura</key>
   <value>      
    <cdCobertura>$codigoTipoCobertura</cdCobertura>
    <isCobertura>$valorTipoCobertura</isCobertura>          
  </value>
 </entry>
  <entry>
  <key>$codigoTipoCobertura</key>
   <value>      
    <cdCobertura>$codigoTipoCobertura</cdCobertura>
    <isCobertura>$valorTipoCobertura</isCobertura>          
  </value>
 </entry>
</hsCobertura>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa.

Comment: @Sam Existe como adicionar condicional (if ou else) em uma tag XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução aplicada foi adicionar comentário dentro da TAG do arquivo XML e substitui-lo quando houvesse informação do tipo de cobertura. 
Utilizei a biblioteca do php: str_replace e acrescentei a condicional IF. 
Segue o código abaixo:

```html
//Trecho do conteúdo do arquivo XML com o comentário inserido 
$conteudoXml = "
<hsCobertura>
  <entry>
    <key>$codigoTipoCobertura</key>
    <value>
      <cdCobertura>$codigoTipoCobertura</cdCobertura>
      <isCobertura>$valorTipoCobertura</isCobertura>
    </value>
  </entry>
  ##TIPODECOBERTURA_1##
</hsCobertura>"; 

//Comentário da TAG que será armazenado na variável.
 $atributoComentarioTipoCobertura_1 = ("##TIPODECOBERTURA_1##"); 

//Condicional para verificar se a variável foi iniciada e/ou existe. 
if (isset($codigoTipoCobertura_1)) { 

$dadosTagXML
= "
<entry>
  <key>$codigoTipoCobertura_1</key>
  <value>
    <cdCobertura>$codigoTipoCobertura_1</cdCobertura>
    <isCobertura>$valorTipoCobertura_1</isCobertura>
  </value>
</entry>"; 

//Variável que armazena a substituição do comentário na TAG do XML. 
$resultadoSubstituicaoXML = str_replace($atributoComentarioTipoCobertura, $dadosTagXML, $conteudoXml);
```